# Attempted to load class "knpPaginatorBundle" from namespace "knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle".Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, bundle

> Attempted to load class "knpPaginatorBundle" from namespace "knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I've got :

```
"ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 25:
```

In my AppKernel I have this:

```
new knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\knpPaginatorBundle(),
```

Also in my `composer.json`:

```
"psr-4": { "": "src/",
                   "Knp\\Bundle\\PaginatorBundle\\": "src/Knp/Bundle/PaginatorBundle"
        },
```

Comment: `K` vs `k` maybe?

Comment: Why is KnpBundle under src?  You should be using composer to install it under vendor.  Composer takes care of setting your psr4 stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here :
`new knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\knpPaginatorBundle()`

Do this instead :
`new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle()`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, What the difference between the two lines.

Comment: In the second one the 'K' letters are uppercased

Answer (score 0):

I have come across with the same issue. The project that I working on uses **Symfony 3.4. version**, **Ubuntu 18.04 and Docker**. These are the steps I've followed:

```
1. Delete everything from the cache folder: rm -rf var/cache/*
2. docker-compose down
3. docker-compose up -d   
4. Refresh the page - That was it!
```